# Moving page number or text above horizontal footer line

Tags: positioning

How do I move some chosen text (or current page number) directly above the horizontal rule/line created by the `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}` command?

I am using the fancyhdr package.

Edit: More specifically --- How can I keep the page number below the rule, but add some text (e.g. a URL) above the line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment has been required to have the page number centered below the footrule and a URL also centered, but above the footrule. Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\addtolength\footskip{10pt}
\newcommand\myurl{\url{www.ctan.org}}
\makeatletter
\def\@fancyfoot#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
    \@fancyvbox\footskip{\hbox{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering\myurl}}\vskip.2\footskip\footrule
      \hbox{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
        \parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
        \llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}}}#5}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of the `etoolbox` package, one can patch the `\@fancyfoot` command and the code simplifies:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\addtolength\footskip{10pt}
\newcommand\myurl{\url{www.ctan.org}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fancyfoot}{\footrule}{\hbox{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering\myurl}}\vskip.2\footskip\footrule}{}{}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I, keep the page number below the rule, but add some text (e.g. a URL) above the line. I tried to use `\cfoot{\thepage}` but then my text (above the line) disappeared

Comment: @Sean And in what position should the number and the URL be? Both centered, number centered, URL to the left?

Comment: Both should be centered

Comment: @Sean please see my updated answer. I would also suggest you to add the complete description of the problem as an edit to your question, so it will be clear for everyone reading the question.